# Merging arduino code

Tags: arduino-nano, bluetooth, temperature

I have a project where we need to create a virtual cane for blind people and it will have 3 functions:

- Pressure button when pressed will connect to an android phone through HC-06 Bluetooth modulo to an app that I developed and will
  can to someone that I defined
- Temperature sensor that is attached to a buzzer that will buzz if the
  temperature is higher than 40 Degrees
- Ultrasonic sensor attached to and vibration motor that will vibrate
  if there is any object less than 70 cm from the person.

When I combine the code from the ultrasonic and the temperature sensor, everything works fine, when I add the bluetooth code, nothing works, anyone see the problem? Or could you show me the problem and solveit?

Code without Bluetooth:

```
int DHT11_PIN=8;
dht DHT;
int buzzer=6;
int trigPin=3;
int echoPin=2;
int motor=7;


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(DHT11_PIN,INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motor, OUTPUT);
  delay(5000);
}

void loop(){
  Stemperature();
  Sultrassom();
}

// sensor de tempratura e Buzzer-------------------------------
void Stemperature(){
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  float t=DHT.temperature;
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(t);

  if (t>40){ 
    digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
    {tone(6,100,20);
    delay(1);
    noTone(1);
    delay(1);
    }
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("ON T=");
  }else{
    digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
    Serial.print("OF T=");
  }
}

//Sensor de Ultrassom e Motor vibração-----------------
void Sultrassom(){
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) * 0.0340;
  Serial.println(distance);

  if (distance < 70){ // se a distância for menor que 70 cm o motor vibra
    digitalWrite(motor,HIGH);// quando a distância for menor que 70 cm
    Serial.print("MOTOR ON=");
  }else{
    digitalWrite(motor,LOW);// quando a distância for maior que 70 cm 
    Serial.print("MOTOR OFF=");
  } 
  delay(5);
}
```

Bluetooth Code:

```
const int buttonPin = 4;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
boolean buttonState;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  buttonState = LOW;
}

void loop(){
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if(buttonState == HIGH) {
    // send char 1 via Bluetooth:
    Serial.println("1");
    delay(20000);
    while (0);
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you done already? Have you traced the execution? What is the last statement executed?

Answer (score 1):

In the bluetooth loop you use:

```
delay(20000);
while (0);
```

This means you first wait 20 seconds, and while(0) does not do anything (unuseful instruction).

Actually, this results when the button is pressed, it starts the loop again, but you have to merge both codes into one.

I would add the sending of the serial command in the code above, remove the while and see what happens. If you need some delay for debouncing reaons for the button, implement a decent deboucing algorithm instead of the delay of 20000.

And why there are two }} at the end?

Comment: `while(1);` means wait forever `while(0);` means never wait, which is pointless.

Comment: True ... I will change it

Comment: No - zero is false :)

Comment: Adapted it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not tested in any way. It should give you some help, to detect the problems. First you used the same Serial connection for your PC and the Bluetooth module, which leads to problems. Second, you had some delays, which seemed useless. Third your `noTone()` function didn't matched the right pin. Also I added an Interrupt for the Button. It could be, that your DHT reading need the same Interruptprotection, which I added to the Usonic measurment. Last but not least I replaced your Pin definitions to make it more readable.

```
// New Include for the bluetooth connection
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <dht.h>

#define DHT11PIN        8
#define BTRXPIN         10                    // Pay attention to your wiring
#define BTTXPIN         11
#define BUZZERPIN       6
#define TRIGGERPIN      5                     // Changed, to keep an interrupt Pin free !!!
#define ECHOPIN         4                     // Changed, to keep an interrupt Pin free !!!
#define MOTORPIN        7
#define BUTTONPIN       2                     // Changed to an interrupt Pin

dht DHT;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(BTRXPIN, BTTXPIN);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);                         // Only once
  bluetooth.begin(9600);                      // Serial connection for the bluetooth module
                                              // Check your needed Baudrate
  pinMode(DHT11PIN,  INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTONPIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(ECHOPIN,   INPUT); 
  pinMode(TRIGGERPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUZZERPIN,  OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(MOTORPIN,   OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUZZERPIN, LOW);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(BUTTONPIN), buttonISR, RISING); // I did not pay attention to bouncing here!!
  // I see no need for 5sec delay, so i cut it out
}

void loop(){
  temperatureMeasure();
  ultraSonicMeasure();
  delay(2000);                                  // 2 sec delay, so it won't measure all the time.
}


float temperatureMeasure(){                     // Added return types
  DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  float t = DHT.temperature;
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(t);

  if (t > 40){ 
    tone(BUZZERPIN,100);
    delay(20);
    noTone(BUZZERPIN);
    Serial.print("ON");
  }else{
    noTone(BUZZERPIN);
    Serial.print("OFF");
  }
  return temperatureMeasure;
}

long ultraSonicMeasure(){
  long duration{0};
  long distance{0};
  noInterrupts();
  digitalWrite(TRIGGERPIN, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(TRIGGERPIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(TRIGGERPIN, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH);
  interrupts();
  distance = (duration/2) * 0.0340;
  Serial.println(distance);

  if (distance < 70){ 
    digitalWrite(MOTORPIN, HIGH);
    Serial.print("MOTOR ON");
  }else{
    digitalWrite(MOTORPIN, LOW);
    Serial.print("MOTOR OFF");
  }
  return distance;
}

// Called when button is pressed
void buttonISR(){
  bluetooth.println("1");                         // Would be better, to put this outside of the ISR, but is is only on character.
}
```

Comment: It worked with some modifications!!!
Thank you :)